# Grails - TypeMismatchException id passed as a string

Tags: grails-controller

I am having UI problems linking to a class entity using the

```
        <td><g:link controller="publishedShr" action="show" 
            id="${videoShrInstance.publId.id}">
            ${fieldValue(bean: videoShrInstance, field: "publId")}</g:link></td>
```

And here it the resultant url:

```
http://localhost:9000/HomeVu1/publishedShr/show/%5B35%5D
```

Which should be of the form:

```
http://localhost:9000/HomeVu1/publishedShr/show/35
```

On the same web page I have a similar link to a child entity that works:

```
    <td><g:link controller = "videoShr" action="show" id="${publishedShrInstance.videoId.id}">
    ${fieldValue(bean: publishedShrInstance, field: "videoId")}</g:link></td>
```

I am using

I have cleaned the project as this link did originally work - Can I cast it to Long in the

-mike

Comment: Does `videoShrInstance` have many `publId` instances? I mean is there a "hasMany" relationship?

Comment: Ron - It is setup as a hasMany but it actually only has one at ATM.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to create your link is correct except for the way you're trying to output the id. When you're trying to output the value of `videoShrInstance.publId.id`, it is equivalent to writing similar to `videoShrInstance*.publId*.id`. It is implicitly converted to use the spread operator in Groovy (the asterisk * operator)

Since it is implicitly using the spread operator and enclosed in a GString, Groovy outputs the toString() version of the list which contains the "[]" brackets. Then it is URL encoded by the `g:link` tag and that's why your URL is so screwed up.

You can change the link to the following format to correctly form the URL:

```
<td>
     <g:link controller="publishedShr" action="show"   
        id="${videoShrInstance.publId?.getAt(0)?.id}">
        ${fieldValue(bean: videoShrInstance, field: "publId")}</g:link>
</td>
```

This will output the id of the first hasMany instance in the list and is also null-safe.

Check out this script to get around this concept a little more: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5768755258851328

Comment: Ron - that solves my link problem. As you said the display of the field is encased in [] as it is an array. I have tried to use the getAt to remove these [] without success. I've tried to put a getAt() into the fieldValue in different ways without any success. I am displaying the name of the link not the id. Here is the html: `<td><g:link controller="publishedShr" action="show" 
             id="${videoShrInstance.publId.getAt(0).id}">
       ${fieldValue(bean: videoShrInstance, field: "publId")}</g:link></td>`

Comment: Do you need to use the fieldValue method? Can you not just use the GString to output the text of the anchor link? Use `${videoShrInstance.publId?.getAt(0)?.id}` instead of `${fieldValue(bean: videoShrInstance, field: "publId")}`

Comment: Yes - that does the job.